# Good introductory references on Shatdarshanas that covers debates, arguments and principles

Tags: philosophy, advaita, reference-request, shad-darshana

As far as I know, only Advaita Vedanta has been well commented for principal Upanishad. It belongs to the Vedanta school. Is ther any single text like *AdvaitaSiddhi* that covers the arguments, definitions and principles in shatdarshnas?